# Which NodeJS Frameworks support relational databases?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm starting server-side development with NodeJS, I have found lots of promising frameworks, but can't tell which of them support relational databases (Namely Postgres).

Any ideas? Server-side MVC frameworks are preferred.

Comment: Just found a project built of the MEAN.JS boilerplate, but that uses PostgreSQL and Sequelize instead of MongoDB and Mongoose. Definitely worth checking out! https://github.com/StetSolutions/pean

Answer (score 4):

[Express](http://expressjs.com/) is universal framework ( and really popular one ), you can use it with any database you want. You just need a database driver. You can use one of these:

https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres ( low level )

https://github.com/grncdr/node-any-db

https://github.com/brianc/node-sql

There are probably many many more, just google it.

Answer (score 2):

check out the modules list [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#database)

there are many db modules for mysql/SQLite/PostgreSQL etc...

Comment: Can these modules be added to (any) framework? for example Tower.js?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with [Sequelize.js](http://www.sequelizejs.com). It's an ORM for Postgres and MySQL. It's recommended in some books about node.js. I gave it a try and it looked promising.

On the other hand I would ask myself a question: *If I need to use relational database, is node.js still a good choice?*

Comment: Sequelize.js also works with PostgreSQL

Comment: `If I need to use relational database, is node.js still a good choice?` I don't see any advantage of using one database over another with Node.js imho.

Comment: Maslow said `"If the only tool you have is a hammer, you tend to see every problem as a nail."` Pick the right tool for the job and IMHO either relational DB or Node.js is the wrong choice here.

Answer (score 1):

[sails.js](http://sailsjs.org) is built on express (see @freakish's answer) and supports MySQL, Postgres, and over a dozen other NoSQL and SQL databases.